# How to set SelectedDate in CalendarView in xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, calendarview

I am working on xamarin.forms. I am using CalendarView in my app. When I am trying to set the SelectedDate on opening of calendar, it is not reflecting on view. But during debugging I found that values are binding properly. But not reflecting on CalendarView. My code is as follows :

```
  CalendarView _calendarView;
  _calendarView = new CalendarView ();
                    _calendarView.MinDate = DateTime.Parse ("01/01/1700");
                    _calendarView.MaxDate = DateTime.Parse ("12/31/2025");
                    _calendarView.DateSelected += _calendarView_DateSelected;
                    _calendarView.SelectedDate=Convert.ToDateTime("12/10/2015 12:00:00 AM");
                    _calendarView.BackgroundColor=Color.FromRgb(72,110,195);
                    _calendarView.SelectedDateBackgroundColor=Color.Red;
                    _calendarView.SelectedDateForegroundColor=Color.White;
```

Anyone knows what I am doing wrong here?

Regards,
Anand Dubey

Answer (score 0):

Try something with this :

```
[Android.Runtime.Register("setDate", "(JZZ)V", "GetSetDate_JZZHandler")]
public virtual Void SetDate (Int64 date, Boolean animate, Boolean center)
```